# Sum of numbers on the perimeter from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, methods, numbers

I need to sum the numbers on the perimeter of this 2D array

```js
const arr = [[1,5,3,4], 
             [4,9,9,7], 
             [3,8,7,4]];
```

The answer is 79 but i dont know how to write function.

Comment: Where's your code? ... Would be an interesting problem, provided you provided your data structure and source code.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing or tutorial service. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: What the programming language name did you mean?

Comment: it looks the sum of the array should be 99 not 79? you just need to sum all of the numbers?

Comment: why answer is 79 and not 99???

Comment: @gpl why do you think the answer should be 99? Explain.

Comment: I just summed it up. Tell me why it should be 79??

Comment: What did you sum up? All the values shown? Or just the outside values, ergo the perimeter? 3+8+9 would be the additional 20. But those values are not on the perimeter.

Comment: OP indented the array in the question to show its shape.

Answer (score 2):

This function will return all the perimeter numbers in a matrix, then flat and sum each item.

```js
const arr = [[3, 8, 9, 7, 6], [6, 3, 8, 9, 7], [7, 6, 3, 8, 9]];

var snail = function(arr) {
    let output = [];
    output.push(arr[0]);
    output.push(arr[arr.length - 1]);

    for(let item of arr){
        if(item != arr[0] && item != arr[arr.length - 1]){
            output.push(item[0]);
            output.push(item[item.length - 1]);
        }
    }

return output
}

const perimeter = snail(arr).flat(1);
const sum = perimeter.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: this function first push the total first and last nested arrays, then push the first and last items of each nested arrays that are not at index 0 and at last index

Comment: Ahhh i see, since the 1st and last (top and bottom) would be on the perimeter as a given

Answer (score 2):

You could visit all values and chgeck if the indices are either zero or the length of actual array minus one.

```js
const
    array = [[3, 8, 9, 7, 6], [6, 3, 8, 9, 7], [7, 6, 3, 8, 9]],
    perimeter = array.reduce((sum, row, i, a) =>
        row.reduce((s, v, j, b) =>
            s + (i === 0 || j === 0 || i + 1 === a.length || j + 1 === b.length
                ? v
                : 0,
            sum)
        ),
        0
    );

console.log(perimeter);
```

Comment: why 79 is the answer and not 99? Which geometric shape is it?

Comment: @gpl, it's the outer frame.

Comment: OMG! I thought they are some sides of small triangles making one big triangle. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(ar => ar.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
```

Comment: Please give more details and explain your answer, especially when using nested functions calls that are not immediately obvious. They may be obvious to you but not to others searching for it.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.